# Given $k$, are there infinitely many $n$ so that $w(n) = w(n+k)$?

Tags: number-theory

$w(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. I am wondering if any such result is known.

Comment: Goldston, Graham, Pintz and Yildirim have shown that for at least one of $k=2,4,6$ the equation $\omega(n)=\omega(n+k)=2$ holds infinitely often.  This is a much stronger equality but not as universal in $k$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't be true for $k=1$

Comment: Actually I found a 2011 citation that builds on the prior result to prove this for $k=1$ (if so, then likely it extends to other values of $k$ as well).  Will post the details later.

Comment: That's awesome as my initial question was about k=1 but I didn't want to ask that in case I wouldn't get any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was proven in a stronger form by Goldston, Graham, Pintz and Yıldırım (2011).  Thanks to [Gerry Myerson's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108357/30402) for the reference:

Daniel A. Goldston, Sidney W. Graham, Janos Pintz and Cem Y. Yıldırım, Small Gaps Between Almost Primes, the Parity Problem, and Some Conjectures of Erdős on Consecutive Integers, Int Math Res Not Volume 2011, Issue 7, Pp. 1439-1450, possibly available at http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2011/7/1439.short.

The preprint appears to be here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2636. 
In particular, if one combines Theorems 9 and 12, then we have that for any $k \in \mathbb N$ and *any* prescribed $A\ge 6$, there exist infinitely many $n$ such that

$$\omega(n) = \omega(n+k) = A.$$

They also have similar results for most other "divisor-counting" arithmetic functions such as $\Omega(n)$ and $d(n)$.

Comment: Thanks! It appears too complicated for me to understand, could you say what the idea of the proof is?

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis Maybe you could post a new question which describes the amount of detail you're looking for specifically?

Comment: never mind, I'll get back to the proof when I know more. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis Take a look at the the bottom of Page 4 and the continuation of Page 5.  It's a very readable example of how the basic construction works at a very high level of discussion.