# Is there any other special numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

$34$ is quite an interesting number. It's the product of 2 different prime numbers: $2$ and $17$. Also, $34-1$ and $34+1$ also the products of 2 different prime numbers, which are $(3)$$(11)$ and $(5)$$(7)$ respectively.

We have a definition:

> **Definition:** A positive integer n is called *special* if each of n, n-1 and n+1 is the product of 2 distinct prime numbers.

**Question:** Is there any *special* number beside $34$?

**Note:** I have figured out that if a number is *special*, then it must be even, but I don't khow what to do next.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/tables/factor/factor.htm
85,86,87

Comment: Note: it is common to say that $n$ is *semiprime* if it is the product of $2$ (albeit not necessarily distinct) prime numbers.

Comment: @CYKwong your link doesn't work.  It seems that you're saying $86$ is "special", though.

Comment: The link is http://www.sosmath.com/tables/factor/factor.html, and there are more: e.q. $93,94,95$

Comment: $141$-$143$; $201$-$203$; $213$-$215$; $217$-$219\ldots$ these numbers are not so special!

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A248201

Comment: A quick computer search finds 13 special numbers less than $10^3$, 71 less than $10^4$, 379 less than $10^5$, and 2377 less than $10^6$.

Comment: Also, the number of special numbers less than $n$ appears to scale approximately as $n^{4/5}$ in the range $n < 10^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture is, that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that
all three numbers $(n-1,n,n+1)$ are product of two different primes. Thus such numbers might not be so special after all.
A slightly more general notion is the notion of a *semiprime*, which is a natural number that is the product of two (not necessarily distinct) prime numbers. 
For the corresponding conjecture see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107911/problems-about-consecutive-semiprimes).